# TS2307: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: json, typescript, github, node-modules, pegjs

I have a private GitHub repo `my-parser-generator` which uses [pegjs](https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs). All underlying logic is written in TypeScript, which is then compiled and fed to `pegjs`, which generates the final parser.

Then this repo a
is used a package dependency in another private repo `parser-consumer`, which is written in TypeScript (compiled with `--declaration` option). So `my-parser-generator` basically offers JavaScript files to a TypeScript consumer.

But when I try to import the newly generated parser I get the following error:
`TS2307: Cannot find module 'my-parser-generator' or its corresponding type declarations`

I've tried most of the solutions on the internet, but nothing has worked for me

#### my-parser-generator

`package.json` (most of the lines are omitted)

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.4.9",
  "name": "my-parser-generator",
  "files": [
    "dist/lib/**/*.js",
    "dist/excel.browser.js",
    "dist/**/*.d.ts",
    "dist/**/*.js.map"
  ],
 "main": "dist/excel.browser.js",
 "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
 "type": "module",
 "dependencies": {
   "pegjs": "^0.11.0-master.b7b87ea"
 }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "dist/lib/",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "tests", "excel.browser.js"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

`dist/excel.browser.js` (generated by `pegjs` so all code is omitted in favor of what is exported)

```
export {
  peg$SyntaxError as SyntaxError,
  peg$parse as parse
};

export default {
  SyntaxError: peg$SyntaxError,
  parse: peg$parse
};
```

`dist/index.d.ts` - my attempt to add some typings for the generated file above

```
declare namespace MyParserGenerator {
    type PegLocation = {
        offset: number,
        line: number,
        column: number
    }

    type Options = {
        startRule: string,
        filename: string
    }

    function SyntaxError (message: string, expected: string, found: string, location: PegLocation): void;
    function parse <T extends Options>(input: string, options: T): any;
}

declare module "my-parser-generator" {
    export default MyParserGenerator
}
```

#### parser-consumer

`package.json`

```
{
  ...,
  dependencies: {
    "my-parser-generator": "git+ssh://git@github.com/my-repo/my-parser-generator.git#master",
    ...,
  },
  ...,
}
```

`node_modules/my-parser-generator` - package structure

```
dist/
  lib/
    grammar.js
    grammar.d.ts
    grammar.js.map
  excel.browser.js
  index.d.ts
package.json
README.md
```

`index.ts` - the code that uses the parser and throws the error

```
import parser from 'my-parser-generator';
```

Interestingly enough, WebStorm can easily locate and auto-complete the package

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

About the declaration for your parser you could use the `pegjs/typings/generated-parser.d.ts` from your node modules as a starting point.

For the message *Cannot find  my-parser-generator or its corresponding declarations*. I suspect it could be because (1) you are saving the `index.d.ts` in the dist folder instead of the package root, (2) the js file is `dist/excel.browser.js`, this is easily associated with `dist/excel.browser.d.ts`.

I would add your `my-parser-generator/package.json`, accordingly to the [typescript publication guidelines](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package)

```json
{
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
}
```